# $readmemh doesn't read the values from data file

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I'm using `readmemh` like:

```
reg [11:0] rom [0:121];

initial $readmemh("x.data", rom);
```

My `x.data` file looks like:

```
line 1: 1 
line 2: 10
. 
. 
. 
line 118: 1110101 
line 119: 1110110 
line 120: 1110111
```

When I try to use `rom[20]` during the simulation, I see XXX value.  Also, I have checked all `rom` data values during the simulation, and I saw XXX,XXX,..,XXX

I'm not sure that I used `$readmemh` in proper way.

Answer (score 0):

When I use your code to read the file, I get warning messages with 2 different simulators.  In both cases, the simulator fails to read the file and load the data into the `rom` variable.  If I add the following code:

```
integer i;
initial for (i=0; i<=121; i=i+1) $displayb(rom[i]);
```

I see `x` for all locations in `rom`.  You declared `rom` as a `reg` type, and `reg` types default to `x`.

The problem is that `Line 1:`, `Line 2:`, etc., are incorrect syntax.  You need to remove them from the `x.data` file.  Your file should look something like this:

```
1      
10     
1110101
1110110
1110111
```

However, I still get simulator warnings because the simulator interprets `1110101` as a hexadecimal value.  Since this value is too large for the 12-bit variable, the simulator does not load it into `rom`, leaving the value as the default `x`.

My guess is that your data is really binary format instead of hex.  In that case, use `$readmemb` instead of `$readmemh`:

```
initial $readmemb("x.data", rom);
```

When I make that change, I no longer see `x`.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.4 *Loading memory array data from a file* for detailed syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the full path to your file. Likely your simulator is not in the same directory as your file.